# Messaging without balance?

Tags: android, facebook

I just saw [an app in android market](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.yy.app2) claims text messaging for 0 data charges.
How this can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses [Facebook Zero](http://www.facebook.com/blog.php?post=391295167130), a service that Facebook has partnered with carriers to achieve. Essentially, carriers allow this data to be sent free of charge. It is a negotiation achievement, not a technological one. If you look at the app's description, you'll see it only works in certain countries, where Facebook has an agreement with the cell provider.